# Add Values to Existing Entry in Dictionary

Tags: python

I am starting out with a list like this

```
lists = [['test', '1', '-1', '0', '-1'],['test2', '0', '1', '0', '-1']
```

What I want to end up with is `{'test': [1, -1, 0, -1], 'test2': [0, 1, 0, -1]}`

So basically, I need to create a dictionary out of the lists. The values of the dictionary need to be integers and not strings.

This is my non-working code:

```
endResult = dict()
for x in lists:
    for y in x:
        endResult.update({x[0]:int(y)})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
endResult = {}
for x in lists:
    endResult[x[0]] = [int(y) for y in x[1:]]
```

Example:

```
>>> lists = [['test', '1', '-1', '0', '-1'],['test2', '0', '1', '0', '-1']]
>>> endResult = {}
>>> for x in lists:
...     endResult[x[0]] = [int(y) for y in x[1:]]
...
>>> endResult
{'test2': [0, 1, 0, -1], 'test': [1, -1, 0, -1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dict` comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> lists = [['test', '1', '-1', '0', '-1'],['test2', '0', '1', '0', '-1']]
>>>
>>> endResult = { li[0]: map(int, li[1:]) for li in lists }
>>> endResult
{'test': [1, -1, 0, -1], 'test2': [0, 1, 0, -1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should just work:

```
endResult = dict()
for x in lists:
    testname, testresults = x[0], x[1:]
    endResult[testname] = [int(r) for r in testresults]
```

what happens if:

- 2 tests have the same name?
- the test results have more than 4 elements?